# Bluetooth LE Characteristic Write and Read Issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app that communicates with a BLE device. The write operation seems successful, but I'm having issues interpreting the response.

Here's a snippet of the log:

`/flutter (27667): [FBP] [[ OnCharacteristicWritten ]] result: {error_string: GATT_SUCCESS, service_uuid: ffe0, success: 1, remote_id: A4:DA:32:4F:BA:29, error_code: 0, characteristic_uuid: ffe1, value: 626f6f745f66617374626f6f74} I/flutter (27667): Success writing /flutter (27667): [FBP] <readCharacteristic> args: {remote_id: A4:DA:32:4F:BA:29, service_uuid: ffe0, secondary_service_uuid: null, characteristic_uuid: ffe1} D/[FBP-Android](27667): [FBP] onMethodCall: readCharacteristic /flutter (27667): [FBP] <readCharacteristic> result: true D/[FBP-Android](27667): [FBP] onCharacteristicRead: ffe1 status: 0 /flutter (27667): [FBP] [[ OnCharacteristicReceived ]] result: {error_string: GATT_SUCCESS, service_uuid: ffe0, success: 1, remote_id: A4:DA:32:4F:BA:29, error_code: 0, characteristic_uuid: ffe1, value: a4da324fba29fb} /flutter (27667): Immediate Device Response Hex: a4da324fba29fb /flutter (27667): Device Response: a4da324fba29fb D/BluetoothGatt(27667): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=A4:DA:32:4F:BA:29 interval=24 latency=0 timeout=600 status=0`

I'm struggling to understand the format of the data returned. What format should the data be in, and how can I interpret the response correctly in Flutter?

This is a part from my function:

```dart
String hexCommand = HEX.encode(Utf8Encoder().convert(command));
await characteristic.write((hex.decode(hexCommand))).then((value) {
  print('Success writing');
});
List<int> response;
try {
  response = await characteristic.read().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
} catch (timeoutError) {
  setState(() {
    string = 'Error: Timeout';
  });
  return;
}
print('Immediate Device Response Hex: ${hex.encode(Uint8List.fromList(response))}');
if (response.isEmpty) {
  setState(() {
    string = 'Error: No response';
  });
  return;
}
String responseHex = hex.encode(Uint8List.fromList(response));
setState(() {
  string = responseHex;
});
print('Device Response: $responseHex');
```

What I Tried:

1- I implemented a function in Flutter to write a command to a BLE device's characteristic.

2- The write operation seemed successful, as evidenced by the log entry [FBP] [[ OnCharacteristicWritten ]] result: ....

3- I then attempted to read the response using the readCharacteristic function.

4- The read operation also appeared to succeed, as indicated by the log entries [FBP]  result: true and [FBP] onCharacteristicRead: ....

What I Expected:

1- After writing a command, I expected the BLE device to respond appropriately.

2- I expected to receive a meaningful response that I could interpret.

What Actually Resulted:

1- The write operation succeeded, but I'm unsure about the format of the data returned.

2- The response appears in hexadecimal format (e.g., a4da324fba29fb), and I'm struggling to interpret it.